# Degree of the graph of the product map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G<GL_n\subset M_n\sim \mathbb{A}^{n^2}$ be a linear algebraic group defined over an algebraically closed field $K$. Consider the graph of the product map:
$$V = \{(g_1,g_2,g_1 g_2) : g_1,g_2\in G(K)\}.$$
It is clear (by Bézout) that $\deg(V)$ is at most $2^{n^2}$. Indeed, more is true: a variation of the same argument should give a bound of $\leq 2^{\dim(G)}$.

Finding a lower bound on $\deg(V)$ is not obvious. The intersection of $V$ with a linear space of the form $\{x\}\times \{y\}\times M_n$, $\{x\}\times M_n\times \{z\}$ or $M_n\times \{y\} \times \{z\}$ consists of a single point, and thus just gives the trivial bound $\deg(V)\geq 1$.

What is the true order of $\deg(V)$?

Comment: What notion of degree are you using?

Comment: good old harald posting his homework on MO

Comment: R. van Dobben de Bruyn: the number of points of intersection of a(n irreducible or at least pure-dimensional) variety $V$ of dimension d with a generic affine space of codimension d. John the late: hah, thanks. If only these things were treated in standard textbooks, as they should... (If you know of a good treatment, tell me.)

Comment: For the basic problem of the degree of matrix multiplication -- so {(A,B,C,t) such that AB=tC}, with homogenizing parameter t to make things projective -- the excess component seems to be the variety of pairs (A,B) such that AB=0.  This is the union of conormal varieties to determinantal varieties {A s.t. rk(A) <= r}, and there are good formulas for their degrees... if I find them I will try to post again later.

Comment: Over GL_n, that "excess component" does not occur. Ah, yes, you mean that its degree should be substracted from the easy bounds above, and then we'll get a better upper bound that could be tight.

Comment: What do you for some small particular examples of $G$? some tori? for unipotent subgroups of the form $\exp(N)$ with $NN=0$, the graph is an affine subspace of $M_n$, so the degree is 1. Also, I assume that you require $G$ to be closed in $M_n$, which is not automatic.

Comment: Sure, assume $G$ is closed.

Comment: Let me go back to this question (which some people find embarassing). It is clear that the degree is at least $\dim(T)$, since you can force $g_1$ and $g_2$ to lie on $T$ and be equal by linear relations, and $x^2 = e$ has $2^{\dim(T)}$ solutions on the torus (in characteristic $\ne 2$). There's still a big gap between $\dim(T)$ and $\dim(G)$. Can one do better?

Comment: ... well, the intersection looks transversal (at least for $G=SL_n$), so the degree should be exactly $2^{\dim(T)}$. Should I write an answer, or am I the only person to whom it was not obvious?

Comment: @DaveAnderson Shouldn't we calculate their dimensions before  we calculate their degrees? If the (projective) dimension is less than  $2n^2$ then they  are not irreducible components and can be ignored. The affine dimension  of the space of solutions to $AB=0$ seems to  be $n^2$, so the projective dimension is $n^2+n^2-1$, with $n^2$ coming  from $C$ and $-1$  coming from projectivization. I think  this shows the  degree in the $GL_n$ case is actually $2^{n^2}$.

Comment: I am very skeptical of the $2^{ \dim (G)}$ upper bound. What if you take $G = SL_2$ embedded in $GL_n$ by the $k$th symmetric power? I would expect a degree growing polynomially in $k$ - the best upper bound I can see is $(2k)^6$.

Comment: (On Will Sawin's example) Well, let us see. If we manage to costruct a projection from a Zariski-open subset of $G=SL_2$ embedded in $GL_n$ ($n=k+1$) to affine 3-space, and the projection has bounded degree, then we basically win. Write $g=\left(\begin{matrix}a & b\\c & d\end{matrix}\right)$. Let us try to read off the entries of $g$ from the entries of $\phi(g)$, where $\phi$ the embedding in $GL_n$ induced by the $k$th symmetric power.  Order symmetric products as follows: $v_1\odot \dotsb \odot v_1 \odot v_1$, $v_1\odot \dotsb \odot v_1 \odot v_2$, \dots $v_2\odot \dotsb v_2$.

Comment: Clearly $\phi(g)(v_1\odot \dotsb \odot v_1) = a^{k} v_1 \odot \dotsb \odot v_1 + k a^{k-1} c v_1\odot \dotsb \odot v_1 \odot v_2$, so $\phi(g)_{1,1} = a^k$ and $\phi(g)_{2,1} = k a^{k-1} c$. Thus $c/a = \phi(g)_{2,1}/k \phi(g)_{1,1}$. (Assume we are not in a field of characteristic $p|k$.) Similarly, $b/d = \phi(g)_{k,k+1}/k \phi(g)_{k+1,k+1}$.  We also see that the coefficient corresponding to $v_1\odot \dotsc \odot v_1$ in $\phi(g)(v_1\odot \dotsc \odot v_1 \odot v_2)$ is $a^{k-1} d + (k-1) b c a^{k-2}$, so $\phi(g)_{1,2}/\phi(g)_{1,1}$ is $d/a + (k-1) b c/a^2$.

Comment: Now, $d/a + (k-1) b c/a^2 = d/a (1 + (k-1) (b/d) (c/a))$, so $\phi(g)$ also determines $d/a$ uniquely (on a Zariski open set). Knowing $d/a$, $c/a$ and $b/d$, we also know $b/a$. Since $a d - b c = 1$, we see that $\phi(g)_{2,1}/k\phi(g)_{1,1}$, $\phi(g)_{1,2}/\phi(g)_{1,1}$ and $\phi(g)_{k,k+1}/k \phi(g)_{k+1,k+1}$ determine $g$ up to sign.

Comment: Thus, for $h$ in $G$ equal to $SL_2$ embedded in $GL_n$, $n=k+1$, by the $k$th symmetric power, the points $(h,h')\in G\times G$ such that $h h' = g$ for some fixed $g\in G$ are generically given (up to sign) as the intersection of three equations of degree $2$. Then there's the matter of sign, which could double the degree. In total, the degree is at most $2^3\cdot 2 \leq 2^{\dim(G)+1}$, so not growing with $k$. I'm curious to see what I am missing!

Comment: Can one carry out this argument more generally? That is, for $G$ a general linear algebraic group (assume, say, semisimplicity if needed), can one find a projection of bounded degree from a Zariski-open subset of $G$ to $\mathbb{P}^{\dim(G)}$? If so, the degree should be $\leq 2^{\dim(G)+O(1)}$, no?

Comment: Knowing that a projection exists does not give much control on the degree. It really has to be a generic projection. For instance the curve $y =x^n$ in $\mathbb a^2$ has degree $n$ even though the projection onto the $x$ axis has degree $1$.

Comment: Let's  consider first the easier case of just $SL_2$. It seems that $a^k, c^k, $ and $d^k$ are all entries of the $n \times n$ matrix,  up to scaling. Setting these equal to $1$ is a codimension $3$ linear subspace which intersects $SL_2$ in $k^3$ distinct points, as for each tuple $a,c,d$ with $c$ nonzero, $b$ is uniquely determined by $a,c,d$ via the relation $ad-bc=1$. This shows the degree is at least $k^3$.

Comment: Well, that shows that the degree of the image of the embedding of $SL_2$ in $GL_n$ is a variety of degree $\geq k^3$... ah, right, that shows that the degree of $V$ itself is $\geq k^3$.

Comment: At the same time, the argument just gave shows that the preimage of a generic point on $G$ is a variety of degree $\leq 2^{\dim(G)+1}$ (at least for our particular choice of $G$), doesn't it? (Not the question I asked, I know, but possibly the one I had in mind.)